# AVFoundation video orientation horizontal fix does not complete full 180deg rotate

Tags: ios, avfoundation, cgaffinetransform, affinetransform

I’m working on a video orientation fix, we are joining several video tracks, each with different orientation (landscape, landscape down, landscape mirrored, landscape down mirrored). The issues I’m having is that the video track is does not complete a clean half circle 180deg. As can visually observed by this demo:

Visual results are as following, Before applying the transform (rotated 180deg frame):

[image: Before applying the transform]

After applying the transform (Flipped for correct landscape but rotation did not finish):

[image: After applying the transform]

My simplified rotation code looks like this:

```
CGAffineTransform getOrientationLandscapeTransform(UIImageOrientation videoTrackOrientation, CGAffineTransform videoTrackPreferredTransform)
{
    printTransformForName(@"IN :::", videoTrackPreferredTransform);

    CGAffineTransform fixT = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    if (orientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        fixT = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-preferredTransform.tx, -preferredTransform.ty), CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI));
    }

    printTransformForName(@"OUT :::", fixT);
    return fixT;
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
[1777:60b] IN ::: [-1, 0, 0, -1, 1920, 1080]
[1777:60b] OUT ::: [-1, 1.2246467991473532e-16, -1.2246467991473532e-16, -1, 1920.0000000000002, 1079.9999999999998]
```

Any idea why the funny matrix parameters for b & c and tx & ty ? I assume this represented my problem.

Please note that in order to debug, I’ve tried the same code on a UILabel transformation which to my surprise produces the expected results:

```
void printTransformForName(NSString *name, CGAffineTransform prefferedTransform) {
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", name, NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(prefferedTransform));
}

printTransformForName(@"BEFORE", test.transform);
test.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-test.transform.tx, -test.transform.ty), CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI));
printTransformForName(@"AFTER", test.transform);
```

Output:

```
2014-03-26 17:07:38.584 Transformation Fun[65788:60b] BEFORE [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
2014-03-26 17:07:38.609 Transformation Fun[65788:60b] AFTER [-1, 0, -0, -1, 0, 0]
```